# MongoDB & Docker: connections from Dockerized Mongo client to external server refused

Tags: docker, mongoengine

I've got a mongod instance running on server A. Server B has a Dockerized container for our web app (apache, django, mongoengine). Server B's mongo client needs to connect to A's mongod instance. I can connect through the shell and pymongo without trouble from B to A but my Dockerized django app's connections are refused.

```
ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database test :
[Wed Mar 11 17:30:49.452307 2015] [:error] [pid 13:tid 140069001664256] [client <client ip>] [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

This is how I'm connecting using mongoengine:

```
register_connection(alias="test", name="test", host="mongodb://user:pwd@<server ip>:27017/test?ssl=true")
connect(db="test", alias="test")
```

And running the Docker container

```
docker run -d -p 443:443 -p 27017:27017 me/webapp
```

I've also set `ip_forward` to `1` as per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#communication-between-containers-and-the-wider-world).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it had nothing to do with Docker or mongoengine (directly). Pymongo 2.7.2 does not support SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication. The solution is to install the 2.8 release candidate.

```
pip install git+git://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver.git@2.8rc0
```

See the [Jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17459) which was helpful and the [pymongo blog post](http://www.emptysqua.re/blog/pymongo-2-8-rc0/) which ultimately provided me with a fix.